# How to Bind .environment Globally to All SwiftUI Previews?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I have a global DataManager that holds an NSManagedObjectContext:

```
class DataManager {
    static let shared = DataManager()
    var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    // ... Other code
}
```

Everything works fine within the application itself. However, I'm running into issues with SwiftUI previews. Currently, I'm setting the **`.environment`** for each preview like this:

```
#Preview {
    let exampleModel = ExampleModel.create(context: DataManager.shared.viewContext)
    
    return NavigationStack {
        ExampleView(model: exampleModel)
    }
    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataManager.shared.viewContext)
}
```

This approach becomes tedious when dealing with multiple views. I'm looking for a way to set **`.environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataManager.shared.viewContext)`** globally for all SwiftUI previews.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

I've done some research and it seems feasible to create a wrapper for previews. However, I haven't found a solution that allows me to continue using the #Preview macro.

Comment: you would be better making a different preview context for each `View` that only has the sample data needed in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `ViewModifier` with all your injection and sample code.

```
extension View {
    func globalInjection() -> some View {
        modifier(GlobalInjectionVM())
    }
}
struct GlobalInjectionVM: ViewModifier {
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = DataManager.shared.viewContext
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is call the `func` at every preview.

```
#Preview {
    SampleView()
        .globalInjection()
}
```

If you want to step this up you can easily create `preview` objects with a `protocol`

```
protocol SampleProviderProtocol {
    static func preview() -> Self
}

extension Item: SampleProviderProtocol {
    static func preview() -> Self {
        let new = Self(context: DataManager. shared.viewContext)
        new.timestamp = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: (-10...10).randomElement()!, to: Date())
        return new
    }
}
```

Then you can dynamically create them in the `ViewModifier`

```
struct GlobalInjectionVM: ViewModifier {
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = DataManager.shared.viewContext
    //Declare the types that you want to create samples 
    let types: [SampleProviderProtocol.Type] = [Item.self]
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            .task {
                //Iterate over the types
                for type in types {
                    //Create 4 preview objects
                    for _ in 0...3 {
                        _ = type.preview()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Make sure you are using a "Preview" context when working with Canvas you can to it by setting the url to null before loading the store.

```
container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This is exactly what I was searching for ^^